# Determining the correct upper bound for an integral in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

This seems super easy. But i am just a little bit stuck here. Haven't done much calculus recently. Can someone help me out real quick?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\implies 18=x^2+y^2+z^2=2(x^2+y^2)\implies x^2+y^2=9$$

Well now: do you remember what $\,r\,$ is in polar coordinates...?

Comment: r is the radius in polar coordinates. since we are integrating respect to r first, b should be .. hmm 3??

Comment: Yes: $\,0\le r\le 3\;$ ...